# Schedule phonegap push notifications

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

What I want to do is similar to an **aplication of a diary or calendar**, and I want that the user recieves a **push notification** for example **one day before of the day of the task**.

I have get to send push notifications from a php file in a server but it's not that I want. I want that this notification will be in a specific date.

I'm developing in **phonegap 3.0** with the **push notifications plugin**.

*Sorry about my english.*

Thanks in advance